# wpf toolkit datagrid column sorting

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

Hi I have a column called Temperature in my datagrid which displays the temperature values. I want to sort this column on click, so I set the CanUserSort and SortMemberPath to the respective values in viewmodel. But the sorting is not taking into consideration the negative values, it is treating them positive. How to resolve this issue.?

Comment: First, welcome to stackoverflow, second, show us some source code so we can see what you have done so far.

Comment: Is the member bound for that column a string? Maybe you should bind it to decimal type

Comment: @whoisthis the member bound to the column is a string which has entries like M1,M2,M3... so when I sort this it is sorting based on string values. I want the sorting to consider only the numeric values associated with M1,M2 etc.

Comment: @whoisthis I want to implement the alphanumeric sorting for that column, since its elements are alphanumeric.

Comment: @NagarajHarakuni you can try using custom sort on datagrid and make your own sorter for something like this. Look for custom sorting for wpf datagird column

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Datatype of the items you sort.

Comment: the member bound to the column is a string which has entries like M1,M2,M3... so when I sort this it is sorting based on string values. I want the sorting to consider only the numeric values associated with M1,M2 etc

Comment: Can you post some of your Temprature data?